# Repeating label of line shapefile does not work

Tags: qgis, labeling, rivers

In QGIS, I have a river which I want to label multiple times. When changing the settings in the placement section of the label setting, it does not make a difference. It still displays the label once.

The setting I'm talking about is seen down below (I know in the screenshot the settings are not changes, its just an orientation which setting I am talking about)

[image]